# PHP two dimensional array prints index instead of value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two dimensional array in PHP that prints the index of the array instead of the value.

Here's where I set up the array.

```
for($i = 1;$i <= $numOfCriteria;$i++)
            {
                for($j = 1;$j <= $numOfScores;$j++)
                {
                    $description[$i][$j] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descriptionPosition'.$i.$j]);
                }
            }
```

Here's the SQL query.

```
for($i = 1;$i <= $numOfCriteria;$i++)
            {
                for($j = 1;$j <= $numOfScores;$j++)
                {
                    $this->Instructor->query("INSERT INTO Criteria_Description (description,CriteriaID,ScoreID) VALUES (\"$description[$i][$j]\",\"$criteriaID[$i]\", \"$scoreID[$j]\")");
                }
            }
```

This is what it puts in the database.

```
            Array[1]        
            Array[2]        
            Array[1]        
            Array[2]
```

Thanks for any replies in advance.

Comment: Alax will you please show me what $_POST array contains?

Comment: $_POST contains strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the parser of PHP doesn't recognize multiple array indexes inside your string correctly.

If you try this:

```
<?php
$foo = array(array(array("bar")));
echo "wrong: \"$foo[0][0][0]\"" . PHP_EOL;
echo "right: \"{$foo[0][0][0]}\"" . PHP_EOL;
```

You'll realize:

```
wrong: "Array[0][0]"
right: "bar"
```

To fix this, as illustrated above, use the `"{$var}"` syntax. The curly braces around your variable expression ensure that the parser handles it correctly:

```
$this->Instructor->query("INSERT INTO Criteria_Description (description,CriteriaID,ScoreID) VALUES (\"{$description[$i][$j]}\",\"{$criteriaID[$i]}\", \"{$scoreID[$j]}\")");
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much. What does that syntax do specifically?

Comment: @AlexOulapour it defines everything inside as a variable expression. Also, it makes your code more readable. otherwise PHP can not know what you mean. "on $date[yesterday] i was lazy" can mean two things: 1. insert variable $foo before 'yesterday' or 2. search for a variable expression $date[yesterday]. Default behaviour is 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 1;$i <= $numOfCriteria;$i++)
            {
                for($j = 1;$j <= $numOfScores;$j++)
                {
                    $this->Instructor->query("INSERT INTO Criteria_Description (description,CriteriaID,ScoreID) VALUES ('".$description[$i][$j]."','".$criteriaID[$i]."', '".$scoreID[$j]."')");
                }
            }
```

Using arrays inline in a string does not work.
It only works with strings,numericals etc.

For objects and arrays you will hve to split it up.

For readability I used ' instead of \"

Regards,
STEFAN

Answer (score 0):

A. Don't use double quotes `"` for SQL use single quote `'`

B. It not efficient duplication `SQL` Statement in a loop

C. `\"$criteriaID[$i]\"` is an invalid way to access array variable in PHP

D. You only need 1 loop not 2

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Criteria_Description (description,CriteriaID,ScoreID) VALUES ('%d','%s', '%d')";
for($i = 1; $i <= $numOfCriteria; $i ++) {
    for($j = 1; $j <= $numOfScores; $j ++) {
        $this->Instructor->query ( sprintf ( $sql, mysql_real_escape_string ( $_POST ['descriptionPosition' . $i . $j] ), $criteriaID [$i], $scoreID [$j] ) );

    }
}
```